# Black content pane instead of tiled background

Tags: codenameone

I have a form with a tiled background which works well in the Simulator.

However on device the background of the content pane is drawn black after an instant (IOS or Android).
Apparently the form appears first correctly drawn because the initial image of the app was created by the build process.

Any ideas why the pattern icon is not painted on the device?

The code looks like:

```
    Image imageIcon = null;
    try {
        imageIcon = Image.createImage("/patternicot2.png");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.p(e.toString());
    }
    Style style = form.getContentPane().getAllStyles();
    style.setBgImage(imageIcon);
    style.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_TILE_BOTH);
```

Comment: You didn't mention if the pattern is translucent and didn't provide images both of which would have really helped the diagnosis

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the image is translucent in which can you must set the `bgTransparency` of the content pane to 0 so the form background is painted. Also make sure you didn't define the `Form` itself to be transparent.

Comment: I have spent a lot of time trying to get this working. However drawing a content panes background seems to work in the simulator only. 
Is ther a working example?

Comment: It should work OK on the device but we'll need a working test case to see if there is an issue. Make sure the image is opaque and that the transparency value is set correctly to 0 or 255.